# How to create scripts to submit data on web pages that contains php code

Tags: php, javascript

How to create scripts to submit data on web pages in PHP code. I like to use some more scripts instead of submiting the data through `POST` and `GET` methods in forms.

Comment: You mean you want to submit data from the webbrowser to the server?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to reload the page, you can use XHR (aslo know as AJAX) for this.

Reading materials:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Other explanation for for this question might be implementation of REST-like interface.

In that case you would be aiming for making `PUT` and `DELETE` calls to the server. There is not good way to do it from a website. People usually fake it by creating a `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />`.

Then, when script receives the call, you check if the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'` is true and look for `$_POST['_method']`. If `_method` has been set, you override the default `REQUEST_METHOD` value.